Changing weigth_loss parameter with epoch number
I'm trying to train a multi output nn and I need to change the weight of each loss component depending on the epoch number. In some previous versions of keras, I implemented this mechanism by defining each weight of the loss_weights parameter as a K.variable() type, and changing the value with K.set_value() in an on_epoch_begin() method of a custom callback.
Now, in keras 3.4, this is not allowed, as loss_weights must be a list/dict of float, so within the callback, I can't change the value in place with K.set_value(). Is there something I can do to overcome this issue?
Here the custom callback I used in a previous version of Keras to update the weights after each epoch:
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras import callbacks

class WeightAdjuster(callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, weights: dict):
        self.w1 = weights['loss1']
        self.w2 = weights['loss2']  
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs):
        K.set_value(self.w1, self.w1 + 1)
        K.set_value(self.w2, self.w2 - 1)

and this is training pipeline:
loss = {'loss1':   BinaryCrossentropy(),#BinaryFocalCrossentropy,
        'loss2': BinaryCrossentropy()}
loss_weights = {'loss1':   K.variable(1.),
                'loss2': K.variable(0.)}
metrics = {'loss1':   'accuracy',
           'loss2': 'accuracy'} 
nn.compile(loss=loss, loss_weights = loss_weights, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=metrics)
nn.fit(training_generator, epochs=epochs, validation_data=validation_generator, steps_per_epoch = None)

In the version 3.4 of Keras, this is not allowed anymore, as I receive this message:
ValueError: For a model with multiple outputs, when providing the `loss_weights` argument as a dict, each dict entry should be a Python float (the weighting coefficient corresponding to the loss for that output). At key 'loss1', received invalid type:
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float32>

For this reason I'm now forced to define the loss_weights as floats
loss_weights = {'loss1':   1.,  'loss2': 0.}

and the callback as:
class WeightAdjuster(callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, weights: dict):
        self.w1 = weights['loss1']
        self.w2 = weights['loss2']  
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs):
        self.w1 = self.w1 + 1
        self.w2 = self.w2 - 1

but now changing w1 and w2 have no effect on the loss_weights values.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape GradientTape   gives complete control over how the loss is computed and allows you to modify the loss weights dynamically during the training process

Thanks Bhargav, but I would like to know how to do it within the keras pipeline (compile, fit, callbacks, ecc)

please provide some sample code to help describe how you used to do it in with older Keras because it's bit hard to understand from just the description.

Thanks Sachin, I edited the question to add some code
